# How to pass data from child to parent on click of a button in the parent React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application with a Parent and a number of Child components. The child components have textboxes and other inputs that change very often(each letter type creates a state change).

I have a state in the child that takes care of these fast updates(So that the parent state doesn't change very often and performance would not be degraded).

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [globalState, setGlobalState] = useState({})

    return <>
      <ChildComponent value={globalState.value1}/>
      <ChildComponent value={globalState.value2}/>
      <ChildComponent value={globalState.value3}/>
      <ChildComponent value={globalState.value4}/>
      <ChildComponent value={globalState.value5}/>
      <ChildComponent value={globalState.value6}/>
      
      // I need to be able to fetch the childState on click on this button
      <button />
    </>
    
    
const ChildOne = ({value}) {
    const [childValue, setChildValue] = useState(value)

    // In my actual application, there are multiple text boxes here, so i'm maintaining one state for each input
    return <input 
      type="text"
      // this function is triggered everytime a letter is entered
      onChange={(e)=> setChildValue(e.target.value}
    />  
}
```

I need to update this data into my parent state on click of a button in the parent.

I know that we can use useRef to achieve this, but people say it's an antipattern and should be avoided. How can I do that in a reactive way?

**Edit: More context.** I have several tabs in the parent, and in each tab you have form fields, and you need to get the value of all the fields of the tabs in a certain moment to make a POST request with that data. I hope this would be useful

Comment: Would be really helpful if you at least draw a structure of your app architecture and add it to the question. Based on my little understanding of your question, you might be better off having all the data in the parent component in state and passing the state to your child components.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I have added the code that I'm trying to write

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the structure of your application, but the gist is to modify the global state from your child component.

You can do this by passing the setState function from the parent to the child as a prop.

```
import React from "react";

export default () => {
  const [globalState, setGlobalState] = React.useState({
    someState: {
      value: ""
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(globalState)}
      <br />
      <ChildComponent
        value={globalState.someState.value}
        setGlobalState={(val) =>
          setGlobalState((prev) => ({ ...prev, someState: { value: val } }))
        }
      />
    </>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = ({ setGlobalState, value }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setGlobalState(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
};
```

When managing complex form state, sometimes it's nice to reach for a library such as react-hook-form, final-form or something of that nature.

Comment: Hey David. Thanks for the answer. The solution works but for each letter typed into the input box of the child, the parent state also is getting updated. But i need to control when the parent state updates from the parent like on click of a button etc..

Comment: Just curious, why do you not want to directly interact with the parent state? You could have the persist button read from the global state then go where you need it to go.

Other wise it's just a case of maintaining local state and having the setGlobalState as an onclick to your button.

Can't recommend enough a form framework for these situation though

Comment: i'm interacting with input boxes and my child cant have any save button to save the state to parent, so if i'm interacting directly with the parent state, a state change event is fired everytime i enter a letter in the input box. the parent state is HUGE so this might cause performance problems. So thats the reason

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the my solution, you can handle this scenario by using context api or redux or any other store,
By the given scenario while onChange get triggered in child component we can update that input value in store and then while onClick get triggered from the parent component you can fetch the data from store and use in parent component, here we can make parent and child component as separate and prevent unwanted child rendering while if any unrelated parent state get updated